# Dynamic Programming: The number of alternating permutations

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

An alternating permutation (or zigzag permutation) of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ is an arrangement of those numbers so that each entry is alternately greater or less than the preceding entry.  (Taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation))

So, We want an algorithm to find the number of alternating permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$.

Actually, The question has 2 parts:
a) Provide an algorithm in $O(n^3)$ time complexity and $O(n^2)$ space complexity to find the alternating permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$.

b) Provide an algorithm in $O(n^3)$ time complexity, and $O(n)$ space complexity to find the number of alternating permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$

There is a recursive formula in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation). But, I can't understand what it does. According to the link, This is called André's problem, and the recursive formula for it is:

$2A_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} A_k A_{n-k}$

But, I have two concerns about this formula.

First, What is the time complexity of it? Is it $O(n^3)$, just like the question wants?
My second concern goes for the space complexity of it.

Any idea?

**Note: This problem should be solved using the dynamic programming approach.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the complexity for the algorithm is  $\mathcal O(n^2)$ and the memory is $\mathcal O(n^2)$

First of all, precomuting the binomial coefficients takes time $
\mathcal O(n^2)$ using the pascal recurrence.

After this notice that in order to calculate $A_k$ we need to use $k$ operations, so the number of operations is $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\mathcal O(n^2)$

This algorithm can be easily modified to obtain an algorithm with time $\mathcal O(n^3)$ and memory $\mathcal O(n)$.to do we just need to change it so that the binomial coefficients are not precomputed. Instead calculate them when needed using the factorial formula.

Comment: Would you please explain the last paragraph a little more?

Comment: If you compute the binomial coefficients every time you use them for a multiplication then that add an extra $n$ to the time complexity, but then you only need $n$ memory.